# Объединить (синонимизировать) метки {"эмулятор", "emulator"}

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю объединить:

- [эмулятор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%8D%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80) - 34 вопроса
- [emulator](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/emulator) - 30 вопросов

(по состоянию на 04.07.2017)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Метки объединены.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38703838#38703838)